# google-chrome - how to enable fps counter

Tags: google-chrome

I use google-chrome 74.0.3729.131-1 on Ubuntu. According to the informations which I have found I have tried to enable FPS counter using chrome://flags and settings but I haven't found such option. How to do it ?

Comment: What information that you found are you referring to?

Answer (score 29):

Show FPS has moved to the 'Rendering' tab in the developer tools sidebar.

1. Press `F12`
2. In the bottom (console) section, click the 3 vertical dots
3. Select the 'Rendering' page to add it to the bottom pane
4. You should see 'FPS meter' 3rd item down

[image]

**Update**:

From Chrome 80, the 'FPS Meter' checkbox is the 4th item in the list. You can also access the Rendering tab from the top-right . menu

[image]

Comment: ... -> more tools -> Rendering -> FPS Meter

Comment: Not showing FPS in Chrome 86

Comment: @Ivanzinho I'm on 86.0.4240.193 and I still see it. Are you pressing F12 first to bring up the dev sidebar?

Comment: @spikey_richie There is no FPS counter In 86.0.4240.193, just this: https://imgur.com/FQ5mH1K

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1124189

Comment: @spikey_richie I would have liked to have an FPS Counter, not a percentage of frames that were successfully rendered.

Comment: Then go ask Google chromium team, I'm not responsible for them pulling the functionality! The answer was valid until Google regressed the feature. I'm not sure what you're expecting me to do here....

Comment: Chrome M90 re-introduced the FPS counter.

Comment: In 2023, the setting is now called 'Frame Rendering Stats'.

Comment: Is there a way to shift it to display in the bottom-right corner instead of top-left.

Comment: @LlamaD'Attore I don't believe so, no. I can't detach the dialog from the top left.

Answer (score 3):

With the focus on the Dev Tools Console, press `CMD+SHIFT+P` (Mac, ⌘+⇧+P) or `CTRL+SHIFT+P` (Windows, Linux) and type "FPS" and press enter.

Doesn't get easier, and it's future-proof for whenever Chrome changes the location of the tool in the menus.